# How do I stack images and move them around like divs?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PDQDRJq5Ls) on absolute and relative and using them with divs. What I'm trying to do is essentially the same thing but rather than colored in divs I want to make them images where the child image is resized to a percentage of the parent image.

There seems to be difference in how these work though like I have to use `.class img{}` instead of just class but also just placing an image in a div make the child colored in divs disappear. I really just started html and I've been stuck on this for a while now.

I'm using VScode and running it on google chrome.

```css
.box-1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}

.box-2 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: gray;
}

.box-3 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.box-4 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="OpenSpace2.css">
  <title>Open Space</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-1">
    <!-- <img src="assets/images/space.png"> -->
    <div class="box-2">
      <div class="box-3">
        <div class="box-4">
          <!-- <img src="assets/images/space.png"> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So I'd like to have images stacked on other images and then be able to move those images but have them stay in their parent element using the top: and left: commands on css.
[image: output]

So i have a solution that worked well enough.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="OpenSpace2.css">
    <title>Open Space</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box-1">
        <img src="assets/images/space.png">
        <img src="assets/images/mars.png">
        <img class="rocket" src="assets/images/rocket.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.box-1 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: solid;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: 1/8;
    grid-row: 1/8;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 5/8;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 6;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

The result is here. The only issue I have now is that if the viewport width is too large the heigh of the images grows beyond the viewport height. I'd like it to stop growing if max viewport height is maxed out while maintining width to height ratio. Anyways you might recognize this. Thanks to everyone who helped.

[image]

Comment: i'm not sure about what you are after, but div can hold content where img cannot, so you need to think otherwise . keep the divs and set img inside in absolute position or use a single div and a grid display where you set columns and rows (amount you need), then dispatch your img tags inside the grid.  grid children can be set to the same cells and can pile on top of each others, it is similar to absolute position but without absolute and its sides effects.

Comment: I don't know if this will get you what you're after (since I'm not sure what end result you want) but it's possible through CSS to set an image as a background for a div, and not even need to use img tags.

I'm also not sure what concern you have, if any, about dealing with different aspect ratios of your images.

Comment: here is a grid example aside the background solution : https://jsfiddle.net/9cnpu5dz/ ratio or clipping can also be done via CSS (aspect-ratio, background-size,object-fit,..)

Comment: Thanks I'll try these other methods out.

Comment: G-Cyrillus's solution worked is close. I can set up the images in the grid so they are where I want them to be. I changed the box-1 height to auto so the grid stays square rather than strecthing about. The strecthing would make the images seem to move around and on as the viewport shrunk the images would cover each other and or stop shrinking. Thanks.